# Displaying photos from Redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

How do I display a photo that I have a URL stored on my backend? I have a card component that is being iterated for all my articles and I can't get the image to display.

Would it be anything to do with my jss file that I have stored for the component?

[image]

```
<CardMedia
                id="Photos"
                className={classes.media}
                img src={photos}
                title="Dive Photos"/>
            <CardContent>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should pass obj with uri attribute to src instead

```
<CardMedia
                id="Photos"
                className={classes.media}
                img src={{uri:photos}}
                title="Dive Photos"/>
<CardContent>
```